# How to execute multiple statement in PgAdmin 4 like we do in Sql Server/Oracle?

Tags: pgadmin

How to execute multiple statement in PgAdmin 4 like we do in Sql Server/Oracle (press F5)?

```
select * from employees;

select * from department;
```

As much I worked with PgAdmin, it allows us to execute only one selected statement or last statement per time, is there any way or any setting to execute multiple dml statement together?

Comment: Use "Execute PgScript" button which appears at top mid area in New Windows of PgAdmin.

Answer (score 14):

pgAdmin (both III and 4) execute both statements. For the first one, it just discards the output, unless there is an error.

You can actually chain as many statements as you want:

```
-- We create one table
CREATE TABLE digit_names 
(   
    digit integer PRIMARY KEY,
    digit_name text,
    UNIQUE (digit_name)
) ;

-- Fill it with values
INSERT INTO digit_names 
VALUES
    (0, 'zero'),
    (1, 'one'),
    (2, 'two'),
    (3, 'three'),
    (4, 'four'),
    (5, 'five'),
    (6, 'six'),
    (7, 'seven'),
    (8, 'eight'),
    (9, 'nine') ;

-- And perform a SELECT query
SELECT
    digit_name 
FROM
    digit_names 
    JOIN (VALUES (1), (2), (3) ) AS three_digits(digit) USING (digit) ;

-- All in just one statement.
```

But you'll get only the output from the last one.

If you're using pgAdmin 4, you just type everything on the Query Tool pane, and then press the button with a [lightning bolt] (or press F5).

Comment: That doesn't match what I see. I have 4000+ update queries in the query tool pane, it executes only the first query in 400ms and show on the query history pane that only 1 record has been affected.

Answer (score -4):

PG Admin does not support multiple executions of a select statement

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/91242)

Comment: @Colin'tHart it does, but it's a terrible (and potentially dangerous) answer.  To the OP: you can try it yourself, just type two `DELETE` commands, then try to run both at the same time.  You'll notice both were executed.